# I'm stuck trying to creating a folder on apache image with dockerfile and docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mkdir

I am a docker newbie and struggling with what must be a basic situation. I tried various scenarios but can't seem to create a folder on a docker container. I'm trying to create a new folder 'alternative-html' which is on the container, the main folder /var/www/html, I have mapped to a local folder and works.

**The dockerfile for apache contains:**

```
FROM httpd:2.4.33-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/alternate-html
RUN touch index.html \
    && mkdir images
WORK DIR /var/www/html/
```

**And my docker compose file:**

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  php:
    build: './php/'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./code/:/var/www/html/          
  apache:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./code/:/var/www/html/
networks:
    frontend:
    backend:
```

Question: What am I doing wrong to make this directory "/var/www/alternate-html" appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new folder on the local machine and then you can map it inside the docker container like this:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  php:
    build: './php/'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./code/:/var/www/html/          
  apache:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./code/:/var/www/html/
      - ./alternate-html/ : /var/www/alternate-html/
    working_dir: /var/www/
networks:
    frontend:
    backend:
```

Here the working directory is changed to /var/www/ where you can find both html and alternate-html directory.

Answer (score 0):

So - I finally solved my issue, silly error.

The folder was being created in the apache container, I was checking for it with a php script, which of course didn't have the folder available in the php container....

Fixed by also updating the php dockerfile with:

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/alternate-html
```

Now folders exist in both apache and php and all working fine.